# Use object from constructor in other class methods

Tags: c++, object, methods, constructor

I've got a class with the following definition:

```
class PlotterAxis
{
public:
    PlotterAxis(Stepper *stepper);
    long position();

private:

    long pos;
};
```

Now i want to access the stepper-object in `PlotterAxis::position()` like

```
long PlotterAxis::position()
{
    return pos;
}
```

but i don't know how i can make the object from constructor parameter available in other methods of PlotterAxis.

Comment: if its a method of PlotterAxis, the private members are already accessible to the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the accessing you mentioned, but you need to store the pointer in `PlotterAxis`, that's for sure:

```
class PlotterAxis
{
public:
    PlotterAxis(Stepper *stepper);
    long position();

private:
    // raw pointer, beware of stepper's lifetime and copy semantics of PlotterAxis
    Stepper *stepper;
    long pos;
};

PlotterAxis::PlotterAxis(Stepper *stepper) : stepper(stepper) {}
```

And then you can access it:

```
long PlotterAxis::position()
{
    stepper->doSomething();
    return pos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but i don't know how i can make the object from constructor parameter available in other methods of PlotterAxis.

You have to store the input `PlotterAxis` in your class as a member variable and use it wherever you need it.

```
class PlotterAxis
{
   public:
      PlotterAxis(Stepper *stepper) : stepper_(stepper) {}
      long position();

   private:

      Stepper *stepper_;
      long pos;
};
```

and

```
long PlotterAxis::position()
{
    // Use stepper_ if you need to.
    stepper_->someFunction();
    return pos;
}
```